# Which indexOf function should I use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've encountered this code in a codebase to add the indexOf function :

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

This is a different implementation to the one recommended by Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf :

Code:

```
   if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {  
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {  
            "use strict";  
            if (this == null) {  
                throw new TypeError();  
            }  
            var t = Object(this);  
            var len = t.length >>> 0;  
            if (len === 0) {  
                return -1;  
            }  
            var n = 0;  
            if (arguments.length > 0) {  
                n = Number(arguments[1]);  
                if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN  
                    n = 0;  
                } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {  
                    n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));  
                }  
            }  
            if (n >= len) {  
                return -1;  
            }  
            var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);  
            for (; k < len; k++) {  
                if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {  
                    return k;  
                }  
            }  
            return -1;  
        }  
    }
```

Should I be using the Mozilla version instead or will version mentioned at beginning of question suffice ? Are there advantages of using one over the other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both from MDN but the first version is from an older version of the `indexOf` page. The newer version is an update to bring the implementation in line with the algorithm published in the ECMAScript 5 spec. Given all that, it seems reasonable to use the newer version.

Here's the diff on the MDN page where the change was made:

https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf&action=diff&revision=32&diff=33

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using Mozilla version on indexOf. It's quite similar to the first implementation, but is more polished (which is not surprising, actually). For example, it will return -1 right as it finds out that given array is empty, and will correctly process different edge values given as a second parameter.

Or better yet, if you use jQuery (as it is implied by your tags choice), why don't just use its [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method?

Comment: They're both from Mozilla but the second is more recent.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. ) +1 to your answer.